# how to put html as a string in python in variable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a html boiler plate in which  i want to put some variables later when i get it so just paste the html as a string and insert variables in that but doing this giving me error that string literal is undetermined this is logically a string

```
txt = f"
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>"
```

Comment: A multi-line string needs three quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `""" your string here """` if you intend to write a string on multiple lines in python, so your txt variable should belike :

```
txt = f"""
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
    </html>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line strings need triple strings, so you could do

```
txt = f"""
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>"""
```